# Entity Framework - Map N:N relation with extra field with Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm trying to map a relation N:N for an entity which has some other information. In fact, to brief you better I have the following scenario:

A **user** can apply as many times as he wants for a **exam** and this **application** saves the final result. (That's why i didn't map the key with this to classes)

Looking for this over the internet I found some solutions regarding the creation of Id properties to save information about the Foreign Key besides the property itself. As I don't agree with this solution because I don't believe that we have to change our Model to satisfy ORM needs, I would like to know if you guys have another solution for me.

The following code is a piece of the classes I want to map. Currently, I didn't configure collections in the main classes and when I try to save the **application** I receive a key violation in the database because it tries to save the User/Exam in the database again.

Sorry if it is a silly question and thanks for your help.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, it really depends on whether you use disconnected entities, and if yes, how do you implement the "save" (or *add*)? The mappings are ok. Please provide the relevant code (a.k.a. [mcve])

Comment: Following your logic I believe the problem is related to the usage of disconnected entities. I got the entities again before saving and I didn't receive the error message.
      Ex.: 
     app.TestExam = _context.Exams.Find(app.Exam.Id);
     app.User = _context.Users.Find(app.User.Id);
     _context.Applications.Add(app);
    _context.SaveChanges();

 Initially, I've created the **Application** object referenced **Exam** and **User** and after that stored it in session. After some steps I tried to save and I received the error message. Why does it happen?

Comment: Unfortunately working with disconnected entities never been easy with EF - you'll find a tons of related posts on SO. The EF designers just left that gap for use :( There is no general rule which works well for all scenarios. In your case, most likely you need to attach the `User` and `Exam` (if you are sure they are existing) in order to prevent EF treating them as new. Again, if you provide a concrete example, we could help resolving it.

Comment: Well, basically, I'm working in a MVC app, so in a first controller, I create the Application object, set the User property and save it into session, so I redirect to another controller, retrieve the Application object from session and then I get the result and Test object and try to save. At this moment I was getting the error message.